# How do I access $_SESSION in an included file?

Tags: php, session, include

Here is my code:

My root directory is: **root**

An index.php file located at the root/index.php

```
<?php 
require_once('root/includes/initialize.php');
<?php template('header.php', 'TITLE');?>;
?>

<div id="main">
//SOME CONTENT
</div>
```

My initialize.php file gets all my core include files and puts them into one "require_once". Located in root/includes/initialize.php

```
<?php
//Define Path
defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', 'root/includes/');

//Core Functions
require_once(LIB_PATH.'functions.php');

//Core Objects
require_once(LIB_PATH.'_database.php');
require_once(LIB_PATH.'_session.php');

//Classes
require_once(LIB_PATH.'_user.php');
?>
```

**updated****

My functions.php file includes a simple templating function that grabs a template file such as my header.php. It is located in root/includes/functions.php

```
<?php
//Templating
function template($path="", $pageTitle=NULL) {
    if ($pageTitle != NULL) {
        $_POST['page_title'] = $pageTitle;
    }
    include(root/public/templates/'.$path);
}
?>
```

My _session.php file takes care of my session control. Located in root/includes/_session.php

```
<?php

/**
* Class for Sessions
*/
class Session
{
    public $logged_in = FALSE;
    public $uid;

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->check_login();
    }

    public function check_login() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
            $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
            $this->logged_in = TRUE;
        } else {
            unset($this->uid);
            $this->logged_in = FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function logged_in() {
        return $this->logged_in;
    }

    public function login($user) {
        if ($user) {
            $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'] = $user;
            $this->logged_in = TRUE;
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['uid']);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        redirect(WEB_ROOT);
    }
}

$session = new Session();

?>
```

**updated****

My header.php holds the top of all the pages in my site. Located in root/public/templates/header.php. This is the file I'm having trouble with, I cant figure out why I am unable to echo out the $session->uid or the $_SESSION['uid'] in this file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="root/public/css/style.css">

    <title>MY SITE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="root"><?php echo $_POST['page_title'];?></a>
        </div>
        <?php echo $session->uid;?> //DOESN'T WORK
    </div>
```

I am able to echo out everything just fine in my index.php file and the other files on my site, but not in the included header.php. Any one know why? Thanks.

Comment: How about `session_start();` ?

Comment: @dar - it's in the session class constructor.

Comment: @oob - Are you certain that the `uid` property/key actually has a value? Could you just be echoing out an empty string?

Comment: Try adding `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top of the header.php file. I know it's included in the _session.php file, but just troubleshooting here.

Comment: Also try a `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: try `var_dump($_SESSION);die;` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Do you get the title and the `<a href="root">TITLE</a>` echoed? I doubt you do

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($session)` and `var_dump($_SESSION)` in your header file?

Comment: ok, when I vardump $_SESSION I get an array that contains the uid of the user that is logged in, and I'm able to do the `echo $_SESSION['uid']` just fine. Im just having a problem with the 'echo $session->uid'

Comment: when I var_dump($session) I get a `Notice: Undefined variable: session in root/public/templates/header.php` and it returns NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_start()` must be called at the start of EVERY php file that is going to either set or get a session variable.  The only place I see you calling `session_start()` is in the one file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

Also on a side note.  I'm looking at your class `Session` and I'm not seeing any `$mySession = new Session();` anywhere to also start a session.

UPDATE:

I recreated your basic file structure and code in my IDE and got it work by adding this line in the class.

```
public function check_login() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
        $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
        $this->logged_in = TRUE;
    }
    else {
        unset($this->uid);
        $this->logged_in = FALSE;
        $_SESSION['uid'] = session_id();

        /*Add this next line */
        $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
    }
}
```

The first time I ran index.php just the `<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>` part of header worked.  Refreshed and `<?php echo $session->uid; ?>` also worked so it echoed twice.  This tells me your class isn't assigning the ID to a class variable, hopefully this is the desired out come as it worked on my end, or you can tweek it as needed.

[image: It Works Here]

UPDATE 2:

Function File (edit to match your paths but you need to return a string)

```
<?php

//Templating
function template($path = "", $pageTitle = NULL) {
    if ($pageTitle != NULL) {
        $_POST['page_title'] = $pageTitle;
    }
    return "$path";
}
?>
```

Then in the Index.php file add this way instead:

```
<?php
require_once('initialize.php');
include(template('header.php', 'TITLE'));
//include('header.php');
?>

<div id="main">
    //SOME CONTENT
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

_session.php file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class for Sessions
 */
class Session
{

    public $logged_in = FALSE;
    public $uid;

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->check_login();
    }

    public function check_login() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
            $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
            $this->logged_in = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            unset($this->uid);
            $this->logged_in = FALSE;

            $_SESSION['uid'] = session_id();
            $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
        }
    }

    public function logged_in() {
        return $this->logged_in;
    }

    public function login($user) {
        if ($user) {
            $this->uid = $_SESSION['uid'] = $user;
            $this->logged_in = TRUE;
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['uid']);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        redirect(WEB_ROOT);
    }

}

$session = new Session();
?>
```

And header.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <title>MY SITE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="root"><?php echo $_POST['page_title'];?></a>
            </div>
            <?php echo $session->uid; ?> //WORKS NOW
            <?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?> //WORKS NOW
        </div>
```

Comment: The Session is instantiated at the end of the Session class (`$session = new Session`) and the session_start is called in the Session __construct method, so it is called every time the $session is called.

Comment: Shouldn't it work though considering that if I load my index.php it includes initiate.php then header.php? I've tried including _session.php in my header.php but I get the same problem :(

Comment: ok, so I tried just doing an `include('include/_session.php')` at the top of my header.php, but I get this error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Session in root/includes/_session.php on line 6` when i try and load up index.php

Comment: Thanks for working through this with me. The $_SEESION['uid'] gets set by the login($user) method in the _session.php file. When a user logs in, their username and password is verified and then their id is passed to the $user variable in the method. I'm able to get the $_SESSION['uid'] in the header.php file just by echoing $_SESSION['uid']. The problem I am having now is accessing the $session object in header.php.

Comment: ok.. so now I feel really bad :(. Sorry. I was trying to make this question more readable and in doing so I forgot to add part of my code. I get my header.php file through a function in a functions.php file. When I edit it so it bypasses the function by just doing `include('root/public/templates/header.php)` it works, but not when I use the template() function. I updated everything above. Sorry again.

Comment: Feel free to call me dumb. Im sorry :(

Comment: No your fine!  I like working on these problems because it'll help me learn too. :-)

Comment: Got it working with a template like function.  My paths will be different then yours.

Comment: Brilliant!! it works! Thank you for going through this with me :)

Comment: Any time :-) glad to help! Just passing on the help that others here have helped me!

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague. My guess would be, that since your `index.php` file in located in `root/index.php`, then your include paths:

```
require_once('root/includes/initialize.php');
include('root/public/templates/header.php');
```

are incorrect. You don't start with a `/`, so paths are relative, and considering the location of your `index.php`, you are including `root/root/includes/initialize.php`. If that's the case, you should easily spot that by the lack of `<title>MY SITE</title>` and `<a href="root">TITLE</a>` on your page. Haven't you?

If that's the problem, I suggest you define some kind of `HOME` constant, for example

```
define ('HOME', dirname(__FILE__));
// or define ('HOME', __DIR__); depending on your PHP version
```

so that you can then include everything relative to that constant

```
require_once(HOME . '/includes/initialize.php');
```

Other than that I don't see any errors in your code.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I am using root in this question just as a place holder for the ROOT directory of my site. Im in a local environment  as I build my site, so my root is something like /Users/myname/etc.